# What is a pool separation criterion?

Tags: bpmn

I read the following sentences in a article.

> BPMN uses Pools when representing the interaction between an
> organisations and participants outside of its control. Within a
> company, a single pool covers its own internal operations. It is only
> when it interacts with external participants that additional Pools are
> required.

and read this in another place.

> **You may create separate pools** for Customer Service Assistant and Logistics Department. But to highlight the fact that they are under
> the same company, **it would be better to create a pool** for The True
> Aqua Distilled Water Company and make Customer Service Assistant and
> Logistics Department lanes of the pool. Create a pool below Customer.
> Name the pool The True Aqua Distilled Water Company.

[see this](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/bpmn2.jsp)

Which of these are more correct,single pool or multi pool and why?

Answer (score 1):

Both explanations are correct. The first one offers a strict way of reasoning about pools in BPMN. In an organization, there may be several interacting processes. It is recommended that these processes are modelled as lanes in BPMN, with their interactions represented as message events. All lanes belonging to a single organization is put into one pool. Processes of a separate organization will also be modelled in a single pool and the interactions between both organisations modelled as message events between the pools.

However, these rules can be relaxed such that instead of modelling each process of an organisation in lanes, they can be modelled in pools. This is particularly true in cases where interactions between organisations are not modelled (that is, pools representing organisations will not be necessary if only one organisation is being considered). It is important to point out that using lanes and pools correctly may avoid future issues. For instance, one may model an organisation’s processes using pools. If in future, another organisation's processes need to be modelled, using pools will become confusing. It is, therefore, necessary to follow best practice.